# How do I access data outside of the then scope when resolving a promise?

Tags: javascript

Noob question here. Can someone elaborate on why `seriesData` variable outside the `then` scope is still an empty object. Additionally, what's the appropriate way of accessing data outside of said scope?

`fetchData` is a method that returns an array of three objects when successfully resolved.

Obviously, the `console.log` inside the `then` scope prints the expected `seriesData` object with the resulting data from the resolved promise.

Here's the code.

```
import fetchData from './data';

const seriesData = {};

fetchData()
    .then(res => {
        seriesData.characters = res[0];
        seriesData.locations = res[1];
        seriesData.episodes = res[2];

        console.log(seriesData);
    })
    .catch(error => console.error(error.message));

console.log(seriesData);
```

Comment: Asynchronous code is asynchronous.  You're accessing the variable just fine outside the `.then()` scope, you're simply logging it to the console before it has a value.

Comment: It's not just you. :-) This confuses a **lot** of people. See the answers to the linked questions, fundamentally the reason `seriesData` is blank when you log it is that the code in the `then` handler hasn't run yet, because it runs *asynchronously*. Use `seriesData` within the `then` callback, or switch to `async`/`await` syntax so you can write your flow-control code even when dealing with asynchronous results.